# Laravel 5 Eager Loading with parameters

Tags: laravel-5, eager-loading

I'm working on a project with a bit of a complex model that has joins in its relations and also requires a parameter. It all works pretty well, except for when I need to eager load the relationship, as I couldn't figure out if there is a way to pass a parameter/variable to it.

**The Controller**

```
$template = Template::find($request->input('id'));
$this->output = $template->zones()->with('widgets_with_selected')->get();
```

**The Model**

```
public function widgets_with_selected($banner_id)
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Widget', 'zone_has_widgets')
    ->leftJoin('banner_has_widgets', function($join) use($banner_id) {
        $join->on('widgets.id', '=', 'banner_has_widgets.widget_id')
            ->where('banner_has_widgets.banner_id', '=', $banner_id);
    })
    ->select('widgets.*', 'banner_has_widgets.banner_id');
}
```

This is returning a *Missing argument error* as the variable is not being passed.

I have resolved the issue by moving the logic to the controller, but I want to know if there is a way to keep the relationship in the model and just call it with a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the laravel code I dont think this is possible as you'd like to do it. You simply cant pass parameters to a with() call.

A possible workaround is to have an attribute on your model for $banner_id.

```
$template = Template::find($request->input('id'));
$template->banner_id = 1;
$this->output = $template->zones()->with('widgets_with_selected')->get();
```

Then change your relationship

```
public function widgets_with_selected()
{
    return $this>belongsToMany('App\Models\Widget','zone_has_widgets')
          ->leftJoin('banner_has_widgets', function($join) use($this->banner_id) {
               $join->on('widgets.id', '=', 'banner_has_widgets.widget_id')
              ->where('banner_has_widgets.banner_id', '=', $banner_id);
            })
          ->select('widgets.*', 'banner_has_widgets.banner_id');
```

}

You could perhaps alter it a bit by passing the banner_id through a method. Sortof like this in your model:

```
public function setBanner($id) {
    $this->banner_id = $id;
    return $this;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$template->setBanner($banner_id)->zones()->with('widgets_with_selected')->get();
```

Not sure if this works, and it's not really a clean solution but a hack.

Comment: I like your thinking. Unfortunately the relationship is in the zones model, so none of this works :/

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right. I think it's simply not possible without storing the banner_id someplace. If not the model, then maybe Cache:: using an array driver. No matter where you store it, it's not pretty.

Comment: Thanks a lot  ; )